# How to cast PSCustomObject from Pipeline.Invoke in C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm writing a command that connects to a remote machine over a PSsession, gets a .NET object from the remote machine and then uses it locally.

However the object I am getting back isn't the .NET object that I had created on the remote end but a PSCustomObject which refuses to be cast back to its original object.

Does anyone know how to perform this?

This method is just one of many, so a generic answer on how to handle any .NET object rather than the specific object in this method would be appreciated.

The error I get is;
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject' to type 'System.IO.FileInfo'.

Thanks
Mark

```
readonly PSSession session;
public FileInfo GetFileInfo(string p) 
    {

        Pipeline pipe = session.Runspace.CreatePipeline();

        string format = "(New-object System.IO.FileInfo \"{0}\") -as [System.IO.FileInfo]";  // Have tried many ways to force it to a FileInfo
        string command = string.Format(format,p);

        pipe.Commands.AddScript(command);
        Collection<PSObject> res = pipe.Invoke();

        foreach (PSObject ps in res)
        {
                      return (FileInfo)ps.BaseObject;
        }


        // no items
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: You can not pass live object thru remoting. Them will be serialized on the one side and deserialized to property bag (`PSCustomObject`) on other side.

Comment: Is there a non live or read only version of FileInfo?  I don't want to modify the fields, I want to compare them with files on the local machine.  I'm trying to write an IO interface that will either work locally or over a pssession.

Comment: Yes the actual filepath on the remote location. Powershell remoting is nothing more that sending a script block over to a powershell session on a remote host. So when the script executes, all referenced assets need to be local to the remote location and any variables need to be simple. Notice that returned records are also serialized and lose their original types. Best to read about this a bit and experiment to get a feeling because it is not a very easy topic.

Comment: I've been working with sending POJOs over network sockets for quite some time, so I understand about the object will be a different instance.  What I didn't get is the concept of a "live" object.  Normally my work flow is, read file attributes, copy file attributes, modify file attributes, set file attributes.  But from the looks of things any changes made to the FileInfo are reflected on the filesystem immediately.  I was hoping for an offline version so I didn't have to re-invent the FileInfo attributes structure.